# Capture screenshot of one screen with Shift-Cmd-3?

Tags: keyboard, macos, screen-capture

We already known that <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> will capture a screenshot of entire screen. But if you have 2 or more display screens, "entire" also means "all of them".

The question is:
Is there anyway (or is it possible) to force <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> capture screenshot of primary display only if I have more than 1 display screen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To capture one window

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> +<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and click on the window you would like to capture. The window to be captured will be highlighted.

---

#### Other screenshot shortcuts

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> +<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>: Screenshot entire screen
<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> +<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>: Screenshot a selected area. Click and drag to select an area to screenshot.
<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> +<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>: Screenshot one window or menu.

---

To save a screenshot to your clipboard and not Desktop, use <kbd>Control</kbd> in addition to the shortcuts defined above. When a screenshot is saved to your clipboard, you can paste the screenshot into a document, spreadsheet etc etc.

---

Apple provides an article on taking screenshots here: [How to take a screenshot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361)

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 basic screenshot commands:

1. SHIFT+COMMAND+3 = SCREENSHOT FILE (jpg or tiff) of  OF ENTIRE screen (or all of all displays if more than 1)
2. SHIFT+CTRL+COMMAND+3 = Clipboard (copied)image of HIGHLIGHTED area of screen
3. SHIFT+COMMAND+4 = SCREENSHOT FILE (jpg or tiff) of HIGHLIGHTED area of screen
4. SHIFT+CTRL+COMMAND+4 = Clipboard (copied)image of HIGHLIGHTED area of screen

Using 2 & 4 (above) allows you to choose the area of the display (or displays) that you want.

alternatively, your display screenshots USUALLY end up being 2 separate images - you could just take the image, then delete the one you don't need...